# how to show only editable files in angular

Tags: angular, frontend

how to hide the readonly files    and show that files that can be edited

```
 initialize(oppDataSelected){
          for (let u = 0; u <= this.selectedFilesForDateChange.length; u++) {
            this.box_validation.push(false);
            this.show.push(false);
          if(u !==this.editableFilesForDateChange.length && !this.editableFilesForDateChange[u].isEditIconNotEnable)
            if (u !== this.selectedFilesForDateChange.length &&!this.selectedFilesForDateChange[u].isEditIconEnable)  {
              this.box_validation[u] = true;
              this.show[u] = false;
              this.readOnlyFileList.push(" "+this.selectedFilesForDateChange[u].documentFileName);
              this.readOnlyFileList.push(" "+this.editableFilesForDateChange[u].documentFileName);
    }
```

how to hide the readonly files

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write relevant description with your code. Read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in the ui there are certain files that are visible where some are editable and some are read only files. how to show only the editable files